# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsed when scrolled

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

1
I´m trying to use CollapsingToolbarLayout with a ScrollView but I do not why it doesn't work. I try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></include>

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/white"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/nested_scroll_view" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my nested scrollview that its bhavior set to appbar_scrolling_view_behavior

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp">
<include layout="@layout/scroll_view_aba"/>
<include layout="@layout/scroll_view_aci"/>
<include layout="@layout/scroll_view_aci_reduced"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

my nestedScrollView is scrolled but the collapsing toolbar is pinned!

Comment: are you post the complete text of your layout file?

Comment: yeap...but in NestedScrollView we have three layouts (scroll_view_aba, scroll_view_aci and scroll_view_aci_reduced) which is a cardview that is set in another XML file.

Comment: i made an answer...check it...i think your coordinator layout isn't main layout

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you are using toolbar as actionbar
  To use Toolbar as an ActionBar, first ensure the AppCompat-v7 support library is added to your application `build.gradle` (Module:app) file:

  ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  }
  ```

  Second, let's disable the theme-provided ActionBar. The easiest way is to have your theme extend from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` (or the light variant) within the `res/styles.xml` file:

  ```
  <resources>
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     </style>
   </resources>
  ```

  Now you need to add a `Toolbar` to your Activity layout file. One of the biggest advantages of using the Toolbar widget is that you can place the view anywhere within your layout. Below we place the toolbar at the top of a LinearLayout like the standard ActionBar:

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <!-- Layout for content is here. This can be a RelativeLayout  -->

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  **Note:** You'll want to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`  to the parent layout of the Toolbar to ensure that the height of the activity is calculated correctly.

As Toolbar is just a `ViewGroup` and can be **styled and positioned like any other view**. Note that this means if you are in a RelativeLayout, you need to ensure that all other views are positioned below the toolbar explicitly. The toolbar is not given any special treatment as a view.

Next, in your Activity or Fragment, set the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar by calling the `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)` method:

**Note:** When using the support library, make sure that you are importing android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and not `android.widget.Toolbar.`

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
        // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Next, we need to make sure we have the action items listed within a menu resource file such as `res/menu/menu_main.xml` which is inflated above in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miCompose"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_compose"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Profile">
    </item>
</menu>
```

From this point on, all menu items are displayed in your Toolbar, populated via the standard options menu callbacks.

- Also make sure that the CoordinatorLayout is the main layout container.

  ```
      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer
in my toolbar XML file ,layout_height is set to "wrap_content". I set it to    "?attr/actionBarSize" and CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolled charmly